# How to install FTP server on Red Hat VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, ftp

I have a windows machine and I need to transfer files from my machine to another Linux virtual machine which I have created.

How do I install a FTP server on those VM's to transfer files via FTP protocol? I'd appreciate it if anyone can direct me to a link which gives a clear idea regarding what all FTP is all about?

Comment: It depends on what linux distribution you have installed on your VM.

Comment: I suggest to use SFTP/SCP instead. Install SSH server in the virtual machines and use WinSCP to transfers files. Alternatively, if one VM can reach the other, just `scp file name@host:/path/to/where` directly.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank you very much for your reply.. After listening about SCP and SFTP i went through google for more info and found a good link where i got to know all about FTP.Now i am able to transfer files to my VM. The site i looked is http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch15_:_Linux_FTP_Server_Setup#.UMB6sOTqmSo

Answer (score 2):

vsFTPd preinstalled in RHEL&CentOS you can use it.

```
# /etc/init.d/vsftpd
Usage: /etc/init.d/vsftpd {start|stop|restart|condrestart|status}
```

But change config file `# vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` by default root directory is according to /home/[login_name]. You can chroot by default it's not secure.